# Efficiently generating a Cauchy matrix from two Numpy arrays

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, matrix

A Cauchy matrix ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix)) is a matrix determined by two vectors (arrays of numbers). Given two vectors `x` and `y`, the Cauchy matrix `C` generated by them is defined entry-wise as

```
C[i][j] := 1/(x[i] - y[j])
```

Given two Numpy arrays `x` and `y`, what is an efficient way to generate a Cauchy matrix?

Answer (score 6):

This is the most efficient way I found, using array broadcasting to take advantage of vectorization.

```
1.0 / (x.reshape((-1,1)) - y)
```

---

Edit: @HYRY and @shx2 have suggested that, instead of `x.reshape((-1,1))`, which makes a copy, you can use `x[:,np.newaxis]`, which returns a view of the same array. @HYRY also suggests [`1.0/np.subtract.outer(x,y)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), which is slightly slower for me but maybe more explicit.

---

Example:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4]) #x
>>> y = numpy.array([5,6,7])   #y
>>>
>>> #transpose x, to nx1
... x = x.reshape((-1,1))
>>> x
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>>
>>> #array of differences x[i] - y[j]
... #an nx1 array minus a 1xm array is an nxm array
... diff_matrix = x-y
>>> diff_matrix
array([[-4, -5, -6],
       [-3, -4, -5],
       [-2, -3, -4],
       [-1, -2, -3]])
>>>
>>> #apply the multiplicative inverse to each entry
... cauchym = 1.0/diff_matrix
>>> cauchym
array([[-0.25      , -0.2       , -0.16666667],
       [-0.33333333, -0.25      , -0.2       ],
       [-0.5       , -0.33333333, -0.25      ],
       [-1.        , -0.5       , -0.33333333]])
```

---

I tried a few other methods, all of which were significantly slower.

This is the naive approach, which costs list comprehension:

```
cauchym = numpy.array([[ 1.0/(x_i-y_j) for y_j in y] for x_i in x])
```

This one generates the matrix as a 1-dimensional array (saving the cost of nested Python lists) and reshapes it to a matrix afterward. It also moves the division to a single Numpy operation:

```
cauchym = 1.0/numpy.array([(x_i-y_j) for x_i in x for y_j in y]).reshape([len(x),len(y)])
```

Using `numpy.repeat` and `numpy.tile` (which respectively tile the array horizontally and vertically). This way makes unnecessary copies:

```
lenx = len(x)
leny = len(y)
xm = numpy.repeat(x,leny) #the i'th row is s_i
ym = numpy.tile(y,lenx)
cauchym = (1.0/(xm-ym)).reshape([lenx,leny]);
```

Comment: You can also use: `1.0/np.subtract.outer(x, y)`, `1.0/(x[:,None]-y)`

Comment: or the slightly more explicit `1.0/(x[:,np.newaxis]-y)`

Answer (score 0):

I created a function hope it helps u to understand in a better way.

```
# Creating a function in order to form a cauchy matrix
def cauchy_matrix(arr1,arr2):
    """
    Enter two arrays in order to get a cauchy matrix.The input array should be a 1-D array.
    arr1 = First 1-D array
    arr2 = Second 1-D array
    It returns the cauchy matrix having shape equal to m*n, where m is size of arr1 and n is size of arr2.
    """
    my_list = []
    try:
        for i in range(len(arr1)):
            for j in range(len(arr2)):
                z = 1/(arr1[i]-arr2[j])
                my_list.append(z)

        return np.array(my_list).reshape(arr1.shape[0],arr2.shape[0])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Check if both the arrays has '0' as one of it's element. One array can have a zero but both the arrays having '0' is not acceptable!")
```

Comment: This is inefficient due to "for" loops, we should prefer the solution based on broadcasting.